# how to use use anchor in html with ui router

Tags: angular-ui-router, anchor

I used angular ui router, just like

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'view/home/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
.state('guide', {
        url: '/guide',
        templateUrl: 'view/guide/guide.html',
        controller: 'guideCtrl'
    })
```

and I can visit in browser with a url, http://localhost:8000/dist/#/home
However, I can not use a anchor in my html
if there is a anchor in home.html like this

```
<a href="#aaa">scroll to aaa</a>
....
<h1 id="aaa">AAA</h1>
```

when I click "scroll to aaa", the url will be http://localhost:8000/dist/#/aaa
and return a blank page.The anchor in home.html does not work.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to happen? Redirect to external website? Or to a default route in your application?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have a ui-router version newer than 0.2.14, which was the first version to support html anchors in ui-router. All versions can be found [on github](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/tree/master/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/), where I first noticed that [it was supported](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/1867).

Given your routing setup:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'view/home/home.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
})
.state('guide', {
    url: '/guide',
    templateUrl: 'view/guide/guide.html',
    controller: 'guideCtrl'
})
```

Create a link on any view:

```
<a href="" ui-sref="home({'#': 'aaa'})">Scroll to AAA</a>
```

On page view/home/home.html

```
....
....
<h1 id="aaa">AAA</h1>
```

Comment: Do you know if this answer is still up to date. I've tried it and it doesn't work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893870/angular-2-ui-router-otherwise-redirects-on-local-anchors-links

Comment: I'm not sure if it is still the best solution. I know it worked then at least. Perhaps dependent on the right ui-router-version?

Answer (score 3):

Use ui-sref along with the href tag. The href is used to point the local id of the page. And the ui-sref should point to the state of the same page. For example,

```
<a href="myId" ui-sref="stateOfCurrentPage"> any Link </a>
```

This will make the page scroll to the requires element without adding anything to your url.

Using syntaxes such as

```
ui-sref="home({'#': 'aaa'})"
```

will result in doing the job but will add the hash to the url. This would also produce syntax error when you're using other frameworks such as jQuery.